# C#: click (where applicable) versus validating event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am recently working on windows forms with visual C# and I have a bunch of radio buttons grouped together.

I needed to call some methods if the radio button is clicked and also do some validation.

So I have two methods,

```
public void doSomeStuff()

public bool valRadioButton1()
```

I can call doSomeStuff() in the click event and the latter in the validating event of the radiobutton but I could also just call both in either the click event or the validating event.

My question is that are there any advantages and disadvantages as to what event I would use to call these? Or is there any particular way is more efficient. Right now it seems that both events would do the exact same thing so why use one or another or both.

Comment: I would use Validating event as thats why its there, but I guess if you wanted to you could use the client event aswell.

Comment: In this case, I know that validating is going to be called after clicking, so I was wondering what is the major difference between using one or the other. For example, is there some situation when one is called and the other is not? Assuming that causesValidation is always true.

Comment: well you don't have to click on a textbox for example to get to it, were as once the focus in move off the textbox the validation event is raised. So It would be better to add it to the Validating event.

Comment: @Jethro Your comment applies to TextBoxes, but not at all to Radio Buttons whose click event fires no matter how the option is selected, and whose validating event doesn't fire until the control loses focus if you are selecting an option in a group where no option was selected before.

Comment: @Jethro You're right that the validating event is more reliable in one sense because it will execute when the control loses focus regardless of what set the value.  Click doesn't occur when the value was set by code.  But you have to be careful about relying on the validating event too because it doesn't occur until the control triggering the event loses focus, which isn't an issue with the click event.  For example, if you enable a control immediately following the radio button in the validating event instead of the click event, you won't be able to tab into it from that button properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radio buttons are kind of strange in combination with the conventional validation.  The validating event seems to be designed to allow you to validate a value once when the user is done entering a value instead of every time the value changes as the user is entering it.  This makes sense for a textbox where you want to look at the completed text instead of after each character that the user types.  But it's a little more obscure for radio buttons.  In fact I think you should generally avoid the validating event of radio buttons and instead use the validating event of the container (radio buttons should always be in an embedded container).  This allows a keyboard user to select/move through different options to arrive at the one they want without repeated validations as they move through the options.  Then when they move focus out of the group box (or whatever container you used), you can validate the whole option group at once.  This behavior is more consistent, then, with that of other controls' validation.  In fact I see very little purpose to using the validating event on individual radio buttons.  The only reason I see is if you want to cancel the user's new selection without causing extra click events.  But be aware that when no radio button is selected and the user first clicks on one, no validating event will occur!  No radio button lost focus and validating events only occur when a control loses focus.  So this is why I think you should just avoid the validating event on radio buttons and just use the validating event of the container or the click event of a radio button.

Also, I think if you want to be nice to keyboard users, you should keep the validation logic separate from the click logic and use the events appropriately.  Things like enabling controls based on which option is selected would belong in the click event of a radio button, but error and warning messages about the currently selected option should go in the validating event of the container.

**Edit:** You asked specifically about when one event occurs and not the other.  I would add this information in response to that:

1. Validate will be called without calling click if the code is what causes the selected radio button to change, assuming focus then passes to the radio button (or container, if you are using the container's validate event).
2. Click will be called without (or should I say before) calling validate if no radio button was selected and the user then clicks on one (validate only occurs when the control loses focus).  Validate will eventually occur for the clicked option, though.
3. Click will be called without (or should I say before) calling validate if your validate handler is not linked to the specific option that was previously selected or its container.  It will be called for the option that is now selected (and the container) when this option (or the container) loses focus, though.
4. Click could be called without validate being called if your code that looks at the value doesn't require the selected option to lose focus before looking at it.

Comment: When I talk about enabling controls in the click event, I guess I'm only talking about controls within the same container.  If the controls are outside of the radio buttons' container, they could and probably should wait for the validating event.

Comment: These points definitely do answer my doubts about the radio button validate events. I have now used click events and I agree with the group containing the validation for the radio buttons instead of each radio button. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The validation event exist for when a controls value has changes, this is decoupled from how the controls value was changed. Was it changed because a datasource was refreshed, was it changed by an end user, was it changed on a timer? Doesn't matter!

I would use the validating event to evaluate if something is valid. Even if you know that there is "no way ever that it could happen any other way".